# How to post on Instagram via E-Mail?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm just wondering if there is some service out there, where I can send an e-mail to with an image attached and that service posts this image to my Instagram account?

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [API endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) you can see that they are quite limited. Facebook made changes to Instagram's API last summer which did away with lots of features; having an endpoint for posting may have been one of them. Either way, it is no longer around, and seeing as Facebook does not want to encourage using their services outside of their own sites and apps, it is unlikely you'd be able to find the service you are looking for.